# Best practices for managing exportable API

Tags: javascript

So i've just heard that creating an exportable unnamed API method per file is a better practice, as opposed to collecting all the exportable named API methods under one single file.

So like in fileA.js inside API folder

```js
/* The only method inside fileA */

export default async function(){
    /* Some actions here to fetch or post data */
}
```

And in fileB.js inside API folder

```js
/* The only method inside fileB */

export default async function(){
    /* Some actions here to fetch or post data */
}
```

Instead of collecting all methods under one single file Api.js

```js
/* Placing all exportable APIs under one file */

export default async function thisAction(){
   /* Some actions here to fetch or post data */
}

export default async function thatAction(){
   /* Some actions here to fetch or post data */
}
```

Can anyone tell me the pros and cons of both practices. Creating a file for every API might sound bad in terms of bundle size and file management... but i might be wrong in here.

Comment: A major con in this context would be that you can't have more than a single 'export default' per module.

Comment: @CoderLee indeed, and the amount of files will increase with more new APIs. Im not sure if there's any benefit to writing one exportable API per file at all.

Comment: By API do mean a web API with HTTP or an API for use with an application?

Comment: @CoderLee yes its the custom defined API for application use. The project that i'm working on is pretty large and has quite an amount of APIs for fetching data. Just that it was written using practice mentioned in my question above. I dunno if its okay to write one API per file best practice wise...

Answer (score 0):

The most correct answer is: *it depends.* Typically for APIs what you want to do is have each file export the functions/objects that are relevant to it's purpose. That is, to keep the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in mind when designing your classes and function. In doing so that you will often see more code separation like a single function or class being exported in its own file.

For example: *a node.js service module*

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * @description Generates a random salt value with a default of 256 char buffer.
 * @param {Number} size integar value for salt size
 */
function createSalt(size = 256) {
  const salt = crypto.randomBytes(size).toString('hex');
  return salt;
}

/**
 * @description Hashes a given string with a provided salt value.
 * @param {String} str String to be hashed.
 * @param {Number} salt The provided salt value.
 */
function hashString(str, salt) {
  const hashedStr = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(str, salt, 1000, 512, 'sha512').toString('hex');
  return hashedStr;
}

module.exports = { createSalt, hashString };
```

The above is a simple Node.js file that handles salting and hashing strings with the Crypto package. The single purpose of this module is to be able to salt/hash strings, which makes it preferable to have both functions in the same file. Since you're dealing with APIs there are going to be plenty of times you'll want to have a single export from a file. For example, controller classes, middleware, services, etc might only need to export a single object which would make a single file per object ideal.

For exmaple: *a typescript node controller*

```js
import { Response, Request } from "express";
import UserData from "../data/Users/UserData";
import AccountData, { IDetails } from "../data/Account/AccountData";
import UserSchema, { IUserModel } from "../models/UserModel";
import ILoginResult from "../data/Users/ILoginResult";

class UserController {
  public async addUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let newUser: IUserModel = new UserSchema(req.body);
    let result: ILoginResult = await UserData.createNewUser(newUser);
    res.status(result.status).send(result.result);
  }

  public async loginUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { name, password } = req.body;
    let result: ILoginResult = await UserData.login(name, password);
    res.status(result.status).send(result.result);
  }

  public async getAllUsers(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      const payload = req["decoded"];
      if (payload) {
        let users: ILoginResult = await UserData.getAllUsers(payload);
        res.status(users.status).send(users.result);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: e.toString() });
    }
  }
}

export default new UserController();
```

To handle Users you have a class with the appropriate methods needed, and often that's a single class or module that exports the object with those functions. So the best approach would be to **use what's needed when it's needed.** You only need one function or object? Then you only need to export that one object. You need multiple related functions? The export multiple functions. Sticking with only one approach verses the other is only going to hinder your code and muddy up your code base with unclean code and/or excessive amounts of files.

You do want to have code separation for a cleaner code base and easier maintainability, but you don't want to take that to the extreme either. As for bundle size, unless you're sending a lot of logic into the client side of the application you shouldn't have anything to worry about. APIs live on the server, so you aren't sending a bundle to the client like in a React/Vue/Angular application.